# Specific routing for all Controller in a specific namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a specific routing for all the controllers in a specific namespace?

For example, I have the namespace "Report" which contains Report1, Report2, Report3, ..., ReportN.

Currently using the default route

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

the mapping is :

```
localhost:12345/Report1
localhost:12345/Report2
localhost:12345/Report3
...
localhost:12345/ReportN
```

I would like to change it to :

```
localhost:12345/Report/Report1
localhost:12345/Report/Report2
localhost:12345/Report/Report3
...
localhost:12345/Report/ReportN
```

but only for the Controller that are in the namespace "Report"

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "Report/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] {"Website.SomeNamespace.Controllers"}
);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as it doesn't satisfy the condition : only for the Controller that are in the namespace "Report"

Comment: This answer is not good for me. I was already aware that I could add it this way. The problem with that is that URL like "Report/Home" will map to HomeController that is not in the namespace "Report".

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the "only" keyword. In that case MVC area is what you're looking for.